# How do you make a switch case run until another serial input is detected?

Tags: serial, programming, loop

I am trying to create a Traffic Light Controller.
There are three modes to the controller:
Mode 1 - the traffic light operates RED-YELLOW-GREEN-YELLOW and should repeat
* (The other modes are not necessary apart from knowing the user can select the mode.)*

I want to loop the function of the mode until I receive an input from the serial monitor. If no input is detected, then it should continue with the current mode.
At the moment I am using **Serial.read()** at the start of the main loop function before my switch statement to select the mode. However, this needs an input, but I want the switch cases to loop until an input is received.

All help will be much appreciated.

Comment: use a variable to store the mode ..... run the display sequence depending on the value of the variable ..... update the variable when a command is received

Comment: Show us the sketch that you have so far. Do you know what a finite state machine is? https://majenko.co.uk/blog/finite-state-machine

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this (it is pseudo code so convert it to your sketch):

```
enum EState { NORMAL, SPECIAL } _state; // States
enum ENormalState { RED, YELLOW1, GREEN, YELLOW2 } _normalState; // State only valid when _state == NORMAL 
unsigned long _time; // _time only valid when _state == NORMAL

void loop() 
{
   if ('serial input available')
   {
      if ('input == ...')
      {
         _state = NORMAL;
      }
      else if ('input == ...')
      {
         _state = SPECIAL;
      }
      ...
   }

   switch (_state)
   {
   case NORMAL:
       if (_time + ... > time())
       {
          // Change to next state
          switch (_normalState)
          {
          case RED:
              _normalState = YELLOW1;
              _time = time();
              break;

          case YELLOW1:
              _normalState = GREEN;
              _time = time();
              break;
          ...
          }

       setLight(_normalState); // Change the light according to the _normalState
       break;



   case SPECIAL:
       ...
       break;

   ...
   }
}
```

Ideas to improve/explain:

- Try to make some specific functions for setting the light according to the current state
- You do not need a delay
- Split functions (like above, make a separate function for normal state, and specific state

Answer (score 1):

thankyou for your responses.
I managed to solve this myself by using a while loop to store the code inside each switch case, my working code is below, utilising **Serial.peek()** and by changing the input ending in the serial monitor to **no line ending**.

```
while ((Serial.peek() == -1)){
          regularMode(ledRed, ledYellow, ledGreen);
}
```

Serial.peek() gets the next item from the serial stack, if there is nothing there, it returns '-1' so i can check against that as shown above.

Comment: Yes, you need a non-blocking operation to check if there is pending chars in the stream. ```peek()``` is correct, but [```Serial.available()```](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/available/) is more stream-related.